# Create a running total in SQL with hours but only using work hours

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum

This might be a strange question... but will try to explain the best i can ...

BTW : There is no chance in implementing through Stored Procedures... it should be made in SQL Query only ... But if the only option is SP, then i have to adapt to that ...

I have a table with the following elements :

| RUN | WORKORDER | LOCATION | TRAVELTIME | NUMEQUIP | TOT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO99 | 1 | Start |  |  |  |
| NO99 | 2 | Customer 1 | 112 | 1 | 8 |
| NO99 | 3 | Customer 2 | 18 | 11 | 88 |
| NO99 | 4 | Customer 3 | 22 | 93 | 744 |
| NO99 | 5 | Customer 4 | 34 | 3 | 24 |

I need to add a running DATE and HOUR by calculating the amount of time it takes from one line tho another BUT, and this is important, to take into consideration working hours ( from 9:00 to 13:00 and from 14:00 to 18:00 ( in US format : from 9am to 1pm, and 2pm to 6pm)... As example ... considering that my start date and time would be 10/May/2022 9:00 :

| RUN | WORKORDER | LOCATION | TRAVELTIME | NUMEQUIP | TOT_TIME | DATE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO99 | 1 | Start |  |  |  | 10/05/22 | 9:00 |
| NO99 | 2 | Customer 1 | 112 | 1 | 8 | 10/05/22 | 10:52 |
| NO99 | 3 | Customer 2 | 18 | 11 | 88 | 10/05/22 | 11:18 |
| NO99 | 4 | Customer 3 | 22 | 93 | 744 | 10/05/22 | 14:08 |
| NO99 | 5 | Customer 4 | 34 | 3 | 24 | 12/05/22 | 10:06 |

This result is achieved by calculating the estimated time to make the trip between customers (TRAVELTIME), and after arriving is also added the time spent on maintenance (TOT_TIME that is Number of Equipments (NUMEQUIP) vs 8 minutes per equipment)... By this, and since customer 3 will have 744 minutes (12 h and 58 minutes) in maintenance... and those minutes will spawn through 3 days, the result should be as shown...

With the following query i can have almost the desired effect... but cannot take into account only work hours ... and all time is continuous...

```
Select 
     RUN,WORKORDER,LOCATION,TRAVELTIME,
     DateAdd(mi,temprunningtime-TOT_TIME,'9:00') As TIME,
     NUMEQUIP,NUMEQUIP*8 AS TOT_TIME,sum(MYTABLE.TRAVELTIME + 
     MYTABLE.TOT_TIME) OVER (ORDER BY MYTABLE.ORDER) AS temprunningtime 
FROM   MYTABLE
```

With this query (slightly altered) i get an running TIME, but does not take into account the 13:00-14:00 stop, and the 18:00-9:00 stop...

It might be a bit confusing but any ideias on this would be very appreciated... and i will try to explain anyway i can...

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Also you appear to have a column called `ORDER` but when you reference it don't delimit identify it, which causes a syntax error. `ORDER` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and should *not* be used for object names; if you can I strongly suggest using a different name for your column and, again, if you "must" use a reserved keyword for an object name then you **must** delimit identify that object.

Comment: thx for the corrections... i believe i made all the necessary changes...